# Scala Slick. Wrong pagination \w Postgres

Tags: postgresql, scala, pagination, slick

I'm trying to make simple pagination using Slick with Postgres, but it does not
work as expected.

```scala
// Table 
// "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
// "users_id_idx" btree (id)
val id: Column[Option[Long]] = column("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.DBType(BigSerial))

// Pagination queries
users.drop(0).take(20).sortBy(_.id.desc).list
users.drop(20).take(20).sortBy(_.id.desc).list
```

But results are not ordered as expected. Users ordered by `id` on inside page, e.g. first page will be like `40, 35, 34 ... 4, 2` and second `39, 38, 36, ... 3, 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you are sorting *after* taking your values. If, in the initial order, `39` is in the 21st position and you take and sort the first 20 values, it cannot be sorted into the correct place, as you sort without it there.

If you want correct ordering, you should sort your users *before* taking the chunks, e.g:

```
val sortedUsers = users.sortBy(_.id.desc)
sortedUsers.drop(0).take(20).list
sortedUsers.drop(20).take(20).list
```

Comment: I would recommend to use slice method insted of drop().take().
sortedUsers.slice(0, 20)

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544393/how-to-get-paginated-select-on-slick-postgresql/ will be helpful

Comment: @KhwarezmShah there's no such thing as slice in Slick and you want to do this all in the database, not in Scala - see http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.lifted.Query