# how to get paginated select on slick + postgresql

Tags: postgresql, scala, pagination, slick

In a postgresql database, with slick 3, what's the best way to have pagination?

- get all rows and do pagination with scala (seems not very efficient) ?
- static query with limit and offset?
- is there any other way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `take` and `drop` methods on `TableQuery` objects. They will be translated to `limit` and `offset` in the resulting SQL query:

```
val users: TableQuery[UsersTable] = UsersTable.query

val firstPartOfUsers  = users.drop(0).take(25).result
val secondPartOfUsers = users.drop(25).take(25).result
```

Those two actions will be translated to the following SQL queries:

```
select "name", "email", "id" from "users" limit 25 offset 0
select "name", "email", "id" from "users" limit 25 offset 25
```