# Slick one to many and grouping

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to model the following with Slick 3.1.0;

```
case class Review(txt: String, userId: Long, id: Long)
case class User(name: String, id: Long)
case class ReviewEvent(event: String, reviewId: Long)
```

I need to populate a class called a `FullReview`, which looks like;

```
case class FullReview(r: Review, user: User, evts: Seq[ReviewEvent])
```

Assuming I have the right tables for each of the models, I'm trying to fetch a `FullReview` using a combination of join and group by, like so:

```
val withUser = for {
  (r, u) <- RTable join UTable on (_.userId === _.id)
}

val withUAndEvts = (for {
  ((r, user), evts) <- withUser joinLeft ETable on {
    case ((r, _), ev) => r.id === ev.reviewId
  }
} yield (r, user, events)).groupBy(_._1._id)
```

This seems to yield, when a nested `Query` type, from what I can see. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @pamu there isn't an error per se. How would you consume this inside a `db.run` block? Say, I want to get a `Seq[FullReview]` querying the database for a list of reviews by a `user_id`?

Comment: See [this](http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html) awesome blog post.

Comment: @insan-e thanks. That does provide some hints, but it involves grouping things on the client side. This is ok, as a workaround, but I believe this can be done in MySQL and should be supported by Slick at some stage. Moreover, this causes all kinds of not so pretty problems with paginating through large numbers of results. In our case, a `Review` can have thousands of `ReviewEvent` entries, and it would have been nice to be able to let the database handle the grouping.

Comment: First sentence says: "Slick is a Functional Relational Mapping" library. It is **not** ORM like Hibernate, that does it for you... :D

Comment: I don't really think specifically using `groupBy` and expecting the library to do the grouping is akin to asking it to do ORM like magic.

Comment: Do you have   val reviews = TableQuery[Reviews], val users = TableQuery[Users], val reviewEvents = TableQuery[ReviewEvent] ?

Comment: @KhwarezmShah yeah ofcourse :-) `UTable` and `RTable` are instances of `TableQuery[_]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some tinkering around, I figured it would just be better to do the aggregation on the client. What that would mean, indirectly, is that if 100 rows on the table `ETable` would match a single row on the `RTable`, you would get multiple rows on the client. The client then has to implement its own aggregation to group all the `ReviewEvent` by `Review`.

As far as pagination is concerned, you may do something like;

```
def withUser(page: Int, pageSize: Int) = for {
  (r, u) <- RTable.drop(page * pageSize).take(pageSize) join UTable on (_.userId === _.id)
}
```

I guess this is elegant enough for now. If someone has a better answer, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can use following example:

```
val users = TableQuery[Users]
val reviews = TableQuery[Reviews]
val events = TableQuery[ReviewEvents]

override def findAllReviews(): Future[Seq[FullReview]] = {
  val query = reviews
    .join(users).on(_.userId === _.id)
    .joinLeft(events).on(_._1.id === _.reviewId)

  db.run(query.result).map { a =>
    a.groupBy(_._1._1.id).map { case (_, tuples) =>
      val ((review, user), _) = tuples.head
      val reviewEvents = tuples.flatMap(_._2)
      FullReview(review, user, reviewEvents)
    }.toSeq
  }
}
```

If you want to add pagination to this request, I've already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544393/how-to-get-paginated-select-on-slick-postgresql/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Bunyod/34d7df43d812f7dc2fdca58de0d06c3f) is full example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is exactly what I've been doing and what my answer also suggests. The grouping has to be done on the client. The problem with this approach is the fact that you end up retrieving 1000 rows for a review that has 1000 events. That is what I'd have liked to avoid. I'd like to see if anyone has run performance metrics for a situation like that.

Comment: small hint: you can use `.mapValues` instead of .map with case